# VSCode error message highlighting - occuring in one env but not the other

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

I am using VSCode and recently created another Python environment through Conda. I haven't made any changes in VSCode settings however I see a slightly different behaviour in error message handling in that there is now some highlighting happening. In the attached screenshot, I show two errors from a cell I'm trying to run on a ipynb file. The first screenshot is how my error messages normally looked in my main base Python environment. The second screenshot is the exact same cell run with my new Python environment. You can see that some of it is highlighted yellow now. I don't understand what is causing this in my new environment.

Again I didn't change anything within VSCode itself. All I've done is create a new Python environment in Conda and manually install packages (whereas in the **base** environment, it is the default packages that come in the initial Conda installation).

Any insight on what this is and how I can turn off the yellow highlighting?

[image: error message comparison]

Comment: Try comparing versions of software in each of the environments.